# Is it possible to have mDNS / Bonjour publish the same service name on different servers

Tags: bonjour, mdns

What I was hoping to achieve was to have a list of servers that offer a specific service.

E.g. let's say that I have `server01` that publishes a service called `ControlSystem`. Now I add `server02` that also publishes a service called `ControlSystem`.

What I want is to be able to discover the list of servers that publish the `ControlSystem` service.

I think this should be possible (for example, you might have more than one printer that publishes a printing service), but when I register the service on two different servers with `dsn-sd -R`, then the output of `dns-sd -L` is simply:

```
Lookup ControlSystem._http._tcp.local
DATE: ---Mon 07 May 2018---
16:45:57.867  ...STARTING...
16:45:57.868  ControlSystem._http._tcp.local. can be reached at ControlSystem._http._tcp.local.:5000 (interface 11)
16:45:57.869  ControlSystem._http._tcp.local. can be reached at ControlSystem._http._tcp.local.:5000 (interface 11)
```

Which is not really useful because I'd like to have at least the IP address of the two servers.

Answer (score 3):

As you stated it: *"is it possible to publish the same service name"* on different servers? The answer is yes.

But not as you have implemented it.

The service name, is just the name of the service, not the name of the instance. For example, for a web server service, the service name would be `_http._tcp`.

That name can be the same across servers.

What cannot be the same across servers, is the instance of each service. This is usually conformed concatenating the device name with the service name with the domain name (in Bonjour / Zeroconf, this is `.local`).
Continuing with the web servers example, it would result in `server1._http._tcp.local` and `server2._http._tcp.local`. 
This instance name MUST be unique across servers (and even inside the same server, in case you would have several services, like using different ports).

The device name should also be unique. For example, in the case of ZeroConf, it is specified in the Multicast DNS RFC ([8.  Probing and Announcing on Startup](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6762.txt)).

---

About your specific case, you are registering in both servers the same instance name, which, as stated above is not allowed.

You should register in each server different instances, i.e.:

```
dns-sd -R server01 _http._tcp local 8088
dns-sd -R server02 _http._tcp local 8088
```

in each of the servers.

After doing this, you should be able to browse for HTTP services doing:

```
dns-sd -B _http._tcp local.
```

which should find both instances.

---

And finally, since you are trying to register a new non-standard service (`ControlService`), you should just replace `_http` with your service name, and `_tcp` with the actual protocol (`_tcp` or `_udp`):

```
dns-sd -R server01 ControlService._tcp local 8088
dns-sd -R server02 ControlService._tcp local 8088
```

And the query:

```
dns-sd -B ControlService._tcp local.
```